# On tap anyplace in List row the navigation link is triggered, have some way to change this behavior?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm creating a list using Scrollview + LazyVStack in iOS 14 and List in iOS 13, but the tap behavior is different. If I put a NavigationLink inside the LazyVStack the link only is triggered when tapped, but in List if I tap anyplace in the row the NavigationLink is triggered.

Have a way to trigger some NavigationLink inside a List only when tap in there? This code bellow is an example, the real project has a lot of components inside components, it's not simply put the navigation link outside the list.

Code:

List screen

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var navigate = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                VList {
                    ForEach(0..<3) { index in
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            HStack {
                                Text("Item title")
                                    .font(.system(size: 17))
                                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                    .frame(idealWidth: .infinity, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                    .padding(.all, 4)
                                
                                ZStack {
                                    Text("See more")
                                        .font(.system(size: 15))
                                        .underline()
                                        .padding(.all, 4)
                                        .onTapGesture {
                                            self.navigate = true
                                        }
                                    
                                    NavigationLink(
                                        destination: Text("Destination"),
                                        isActive: $navigate,
                                        label: {
                                            EmptyView()
                                        })
                                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                                }
                            }
                            
                            Text("Description of item")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .navigationBarTitle("")
        }
    }
}
```

VList component

```
import SwiftUI

struct VList<Content:View>: View {
    
    var content: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                    content()
                }
            }
        } else {
            List {
                content()
                    .padding(.horizontal, -20)
            }
            .onAppear {
                UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
                UITableViewCell.appearance().selectionStyle = .none
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give a background to VStack and also using `onTapGesture`. So I do not know what is your app Color or background I gave invisible Color, you can replace it with your Color. Also note that you should tell to SwiftUI that background is in used and it makes that SwiftUI does not apply actions to all VStack.

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var navigate = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(0..<3) { index in
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            HStack {
                                Text("Item title")
                                    .font(.system(size: 17))
                                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                    .frame(idealWidth: .infinity, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                    .padding(.all, 4)
                                
                                ZStack {
                                    Text("See more")
                                        .font(.system(size: 15))
                                        .underline()
                                        .padding(.all, 4)
                                        .onTapGesture {
                                            self.navigate = true
                                        }
                                    
                                    NavigationLink(
                                        destination: Text("Destination"),
                                        isActive: $navigate,
                                        label: {
                                            EmptyView()
                                        })
                                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                                }
                            }
                            
                            
                            Text("Description of item")
                        }
                        .background(Color.white.opacity(0.01).onTapGesture { })    // << : Here
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .navigationBarTitle("")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This work perfectly for the tap outside the Text, but when I click in Text("See more") the NavigationLink is triggered 3 times and the navigation is return to the List screen, not the Destination screen.

Comment: sorry, I post the wrong code at first place, I should send **.background(Color.white.opacity(0.01).onTapGesture { })** and sent this wrong **.background(Color.clear.onTapGesture { })** try again! try with **white.opacity(0.01)**

Comment: The tap problem is fixed using your suggestion, bug the navigation is not working properly [video of bug](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vWBHSU2fWk0&ab_channel=IsaqueHernandes)

Comment: So that is again another issue and need new Question, I can help you there as well but that issue is not connected to this question, You can run my given code in my answer, I mean just **ContentView** and it will work perfectly without issue, the issue you put video is another issue in another part of your code, not in **ContentView**, So I think you can accept my answer here and we work on that issue together on new question.

Comment: The problem is occurring in **ContentView** too, but only in iOS 13, in iOS 14 this code work perfectly. Because of this I ask in comments, but if you prefer I can create another question.

Comment: The reason is: the issue could be solved better with better topic for question also could be helpful for others in future to solve their issue with your question, also as you know stackOverFlow does not like we answer multi issue in one issue.